# View all Growl notifications

Tags: notifications, growl

Does [Growl](http://growl.info/) logs all the notifications that it handles? And if yes, is it possible to view a list with all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a built-in feature so you won't be able to view past logs.  However, you used to be able to enable/disable logging of notifications with scripts I've included below but I don't know if these still work.  If they do, then you could enable logging of future notifications.

---

Enable Growl Notification Logging:

```
#!/bin/zsh -f

function growl_setdefault { defaults write com.growl.growlhelperapp $* }

growl_setdefault 'Custom log history 1' "$HOME/Library/Logs/Growl.log"
growl_setdefault 'GrowlLogType' -int 1
growl_setdefault 'GrowlLoggingEnabled' -bool YES
```

---

Disable Growl Notification Logging:

```
#!/bin/zsh -f

function growl_setdefault { defaults write com.growl.growlhelperapp $* }

growl_setdefault 'GrowlLoggingEnabled' -bool NO
```

Comment: Yep, it works. I also found the script here: http://code.google.com/p/growl/downloads/detail?name=GrowlLoggingScripts.zip&can=2&q=

Answer (score 0):

just go to growl preferences in system preferences and tick the option to log. Youcan then view growl logs by clicking on the open console app button in growl preferences - too easy!

Comment: I’m referring to the 1.2.2 version, which doesn’t log anything natively.